# How to keep size proportions for div's child elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

**TL;DR: How to keep the div children proportional to the div itself?**

I have a div, containing various elements like text, images, icons etc. It keeps 16:9 aspect ratio and fills as much viewport it can, while resizing the browser window, the div (with background different from the body background) changes size well, though the contents are staying the same size which is bad because I'm trying to make a presentation website which needs to look the same at various resolutions. How do I make the child elements align and resize properly inside the div?

I tried using viewport units though it didn't turn out really well.

## My Code:

**I tried using `%` units to set font size and then use `em` to scale other things but it didn't work. I also tried using only `%` units to set all properties but it did not work either**

```css
body {
    background: black;
    user-select: none;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}
.container2 {
    overflow: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.presentation-place {
    user-select: none;
    background: white;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    align-items: center;
    aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
}
@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 16 / 9) {
    .presentation-place {
        width: 100vw;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 16 / 9) {
    .presentation-place {
        height: 100vh;
    }
}
.slide {
    font-size: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: red;
    background-position: center center;
}
.title1 {
    margin-left: 1em;
    font-size: 6em;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="presentation-place">
                <div class="slide s1">
                    <h1 class="title1">test</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it based on some grid? Have you tried css `aspect-ratio` ? How could contents change the size, you want to scale them up?

Comment: I guess you should use `font-size: 1%` or `1vw` to set `em`  units and base other on them

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to avoid specific units like cm, px etc because those are fixed units no matter the scale of the site itself or the monitor, the use of Units like % since vh/vw didnt work. % scales relative to the size of the monitor or website, so this should help. Alternativly you could use aspect-ratio because it scales relative to the size of the parent element

Comment: It did not work, I updated my post with my code.